# Should I offer to come to campus if given a phone interview?

Tags: interview, visiting

I applied to a faculty position at a university (a small state school) near my hometown and I just received an email invitation for a Skype interview later this week. Coincidentally, I am visiting my parents' house this week, which is about a 20 minute drive from the institution offering the interview.

**Would it be weird if I mentioned that I am nearby and/or offered to come in and meet some of the members of the department in person while I'm here?**

I didn't mention anywhere in my application that I grew up nearby nor did I indicate that I have family here. I did all of my studies out-of-state and I'm currently living on the other side of the country. However, I am excited about the opportunity to move back "home"!

Answer (score 8):

It is worth asking and is probably worth a visit even if they would rather stick to a Skype interview. They may prefer that so as to treat all candidates equally, but if that isn't necessary, they might prefer you to come in person.

It is a good way to get a feel of a place and to meet a few students and several faculty. I don't see any downside in asking.

"I'm actually quite close and could easily arrange a face to face visit. Would that be preferable?"

Answer (score -2):

Do not offer to come by as it might be interpreted as a request for special or biased treatment.  You can mention that you are nearby.  It is highly likely that all candidates will be interviewed using the same technology, even if they work on campus, because it is considered fairer.